# using maxima to plot a function generates an empty graph

Tags: maxima

I have the following function and I want to plot this from t=0 to t=10^4, but Maxima returns me an empty plot, I ploted same function with other software and I hadn't any problem

```
h(t):=N0*(n^4*(e^((1-n)*t)/n^2)/(1-n)^2-(n^2/(e^(t/n))));
N0:7*10^3;n:10^3;
plot2d(h(t),[t,0,1*10^4]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maxima predefined constants start with a `%` (try `??%` at the prompt to check which, or simply `%e,numer` or `%phi,numer` for a couple of examples)

Se replace `e` by `%e`:

```
h(t):=N0*(n^4*(%e^((1-n)*t)/n^2)/(1-n)^2-(n^2/(%e^(t/n))));
```

in this case it is also possible - and advisable? - to replace by `exp()`:

```
h(t):=N0*(n^4*(exp((1-n)*t)/n^2)/(1-n)^2-(n^2/(exp(t/n))));
```

Both of these should work just the same.

(edit)
You could also define `e`'s value: `e:2.718281828459045`. That would be silly, but serves to point that to Maxima your `e` is simply a regular variable, just as much as `n` or `N0`, so it ended up assigned to an "empty" value, causing the "expression evaluates to non-numeric value" error.

Answer (score 2):

Also, instead of writing 1*10^4 write 1e4. It is easier and avoids having to use parenthesis; for instance, the inverse of that number is 1/1e4, while 1/1*10^4 does not give the inverse but the same original number.